# How to add a horizontal split to tmux window that spans the whole width of the parent window?

Tags: tmux

When I have a tmux window vertically split into two panes, how can i spawn a new third horizontal pane that stretches over the full width?

e.g. How do I get from this:

`Ctr-b %`

```
+–––––––––+–––––––––+
|         |         |
|         |         |
|         |         |  
|         |         |
|         |         |
+–––––––––+–––––––––+
```

---

to this?

`Ctr-b %`
`Ctr-b` ...now what?

```
+–––––––––+–––––––––+
|         |         |
|         |         |
|         |         |  
|         |         |
|         |         |
+–––––––––+–––––––––+
|                   |
|                   |
+–––––––––––––––––––+
```

---

instead of this?

`Ctr-b %`
`Ctr-b "`

```
+––––––––+––––––––––+
|        |          |
|        |          |  
|        |          |
|        |          |
|        |          |
|        +––––––––––+
|        |          |  
|        |          |
+––––––––+––––––––––+
```

Note: I don't want to cycle through all possible layout combinations via `Ctr-b Space` to eventually get to the desired layout - it should be achieved with as much brevity as possible.

Comment: it's amazing that this isn't a solved problem. All of the answers below so far are completely useless and don't address your actual question :-(

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use one of the five preset layout modes (tiled) to achieve this. From your starting point (a single vertical split), open a new pane, which by default will split the active pane and then arrange the panes into tiled mode:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>,<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>

From `man tmux`:

> M-1 to M-5     Arrange panes in one of the five preset layouts: even-horizontal,even-vertical, main-horizontal, main-vertical, or tiled.

You could optionally add a `select-layout tiled` to a keybind in your `.tmux.conf` if this was a layout you wanted regularly.

Comment: I cried when got to know that `tmux` has presets after years of using it.

Comment: What keys do you press on Mac? `Ctrl b`, `Option 5` is not working for me.

Comment: It's `Ctrl b` `Esc 5` in Mac

Answer (score 37):

tmux 2.3 supports the `-f` switch in `split-window` which does exactly what you are looking for (check man [here](https://gist.github.com/sdondley/b01cc5bb1169c8c83401e438a652b84e#creating-a-new-pane-on-the-left-right-top-or-bottom-of-a-window-with--f--b-and--h-options)):

> The -f option creates a new pane spanning the full window height (with -h) or full window width (with -v), instead of splitting the active pane.

For example, in your case:

1. <kbd>CTRL - b</kbd>+<kbd>%</kbd>

```
+–––––––––+–––––––––+
|         |         |
|         |         |
|         |         |  
|         |         |
|         |         |
|         |         |
|         |         |
|         |         |
+–––––––––––––––––––+
```

---

2. <kbd>CTRL - b</kbd> `:splitw -fv`

*Note that after <kbd>CTRL-b</kbd> you will be typing in the tmux command-prompt (look at the bottom bar).*

```
+–––––––––+–––––––––+
|         |         |
|         |         |
|         |         |  
|         |         |
+–––––––––+–––––––––+
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
+–––––––––––––––––––+
```

---

To have this ready as a keyboard shortcut <kbd>CTRL-b</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> add the following in your `tmux.conf` :

```
bind-key - splitw -fw
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer

Comment: Is there any way to make this a hot key combination? E.g. Ctrl-B + " + "

Answer (score 22):

Get a newer version of tmux (at least 2.3).

From the man page:

> The `-f` option creates a new pane spanning the full window height (with `-h`) or full window width (with `-v`), instead of splitting the active pane.

Comment: good answer, but an example or two would be most illustrative

Answer (score 5):

If you'd like to spawn a new third horizontal pane that stretches over the full width, I suggest you try this

> Ctrl-b "

or to cycle through

> Ctrl-b space

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I don't want to cycle through all possible layouts though, but simply spawn a third pane with the desired layout and position. 
But maybe your suggestion is the only possible solution to achieve this (which I hope it is not :)

Comment: @elementz did the ctrl-b " double quotes work??

Comment: No. That `ctr-b "` creates what you can see in my third example above.

Answer (score 4):

I wound up here looking for a way to move an existing pane to the left, right, top, or botton of the terminal and span the full height or width.

If anyone else ends up here looking for the same thing, the solution is to use `split-window`, `swap-pane`, and then `kill-pane` together.

For example, add this to your `.tmux.conf` file:

```
# Pane moving
bind S-Left  split-window -hbf \; swap-pane -t ! \; kill-pane -t !
bind S-Right split-window -hf  \; swap-pane -t ! \; kill-pane -t !
bind S-Up    split-window -bf  \; swap-pane -t ! \; kill-pane -t !
bind S-Down  split-window -f   \; swap-pane -t ! \; kill-pane -t !
```

Then you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> to move the current pane to the left side of the terminal, spanning its full height.

Comment: I prefer, UDLR, but these work great.

Answer (score 3):

Old question but wanted to add, if there is a layout you want to use often you can use

```
   tmux list-windows
```

to give you the current layout (this will be a string like `c904,273x74,0,0{81x74,0,0[81x29,0,0,1,81x21,0,30,2,81x22,0,52,3],191x74,82,0,0}`)

Then pass that string to `select-layout` to apply it.  Look for `select-layout` in the man page for more info.

Comment: that's a great supplement!

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + B then " (double quotes) to split into two horizontal windows

Ctrl + B "o" to switch back to top window (check your cursor, that will tell you where you are)

Ctrl + B then % (shift + 5) to split the top window

That should work with the default key bindings.

Comment: Thx for trying to answer my question, but the starting point is NOT a blank slate, but an already vertically split window.